# How to increase audio levels on Xfce?

Tags: unity, sound, xfce, settings

I have Ubuntu installed and installed Xfce as the interface which I run because it's faster.

Since I am using a laptop, my speakers are sometimes much lower than what I like them to be which is why I use Ubuntu audio settings of past 100%, adjust it to 150% then adjust it in the desired program.

However sometime's this is troublesome for Xfce because it might reset itself, then I will have to log out and boot into unity set it to 150% to get it working.

Is there anyway of opening this up in Xfce or in the terminal so I can increase to 150% and is it possible to go beyond that?

The 100% option in xfce is not adequate and is much lower than in Windows 7.

Comment: You can try in a terminal: `alsamixer`. Then use the up arrow key to increase the **Master** (press `Esc` to exit). You can try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316331) too.

Answer (score 2):

In PulseAudio Volume Control there is an option to set the volume up to 153%.

You can get it using this command: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and launch it with the command: `pavucontrol` (or launch it through the GUI).

Answer (score 0):

If you have multimedia keys on your keyboard I'd advise that you to install xfce4-volumed and to launch it at startup. It will automatically detect volume keys and bind them to increase/decrease the volume. It also handles mute keys.

If you don't have that you can do it the boring way:

- Command to lower volume: amixer set Master 5dB-
- Command to raise volume: amixer set Master 5dB+ unmute
- Command to switch from mute/unmute: amixer set Master toggle

This should all work from the command line but eventually you'll want to use keyboard shortcuts. To do that use the keyboard settings in Settings->keyboard.